# Junit: expect / assertThrows doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

How look my code, where exception was thrown:
(Lets say it is  UserService.generate() )

```
try {
  UrlDecoder.decode(someString); // invalid somestring here
  ...
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | RuntimeException e) {
  customLogger("Exception message here");
}
```

How i am trying to catch this exception in test:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentExeception.class)
public void test() {
 UserService u = new UserService();
 u.generate("invalidString");
}
```

RESULT:

```
//info logs here
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "^I"
//Exception details here
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: The method doesn't throw the exception - you're explicitly catching it

Comment: Then how can i assert catch exception ? Thank you

Comment: TBH, the code as it's written right now doesn't really cater to testing expcetions. The best I can think about is to mock the customLogger and verify it got the expected message

Comment: Okey, can you move it to answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-) for URLDecoder.decode(someString) states that it will not throw an exception. I believe you meant to use URLDecoder.decode(someString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()). But the Unsupported encoding exception is only thrown if the Charset you ask for is not supported. Here's one way you can make the exception get thrown, along with a way to check that it was thrown. This answer uses [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/), which is a very powerful mocking framework.

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class UserService {
    public void generate(String someString, String encoding) {
        try {
            URLDecoder.decode(someString, encoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            customLogger("Exception message here");
        }
    }

    public void customLogger(String string) {
        // Do something
    }
}

@Test
public void testThrowsOnBadEncoding() {
     UserService u = Mockito.spy(new UserService());
     u.generate("vl%23%46", "unknown");
     Mockito.verify(u).customLogger("Exception message here");
}
```